# OSX: Enumerate screens while on Login Window

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to enumerate the screens via command line on OSX while on the loginscreen (using ssh).

But both `[NSScreen screens]` and `CGGetActiveDisplays` both return 0 screens. Is there another method of screen enumeration?

Comment: Have you tried [`CGGetOnlineDisplayList()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454964-cggetonlinedisplaylist?language=objc)? If a display is online, it is not necessarily active.

Comment: Hmmm. Lets assume it works (I will test this asap), is there also a possibility to check if a display is active? otherwise its not useful for my use case, as I want to capture the image of the active screens.

Comment: Yes, there is: [`CGDisplayIsActive()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455222-cgdisplayisactive?language=objc). Also note the multitude of related functions at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Does not work either unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pre-login agent can enumerate displays using CGGetOnlineDisplayList.

I used the sample Apple code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PreLoginAgents).

Modified it to link CoreGraphics, and added the following code to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method:

```
CGDirectDisplayID displays[10];
uint32_t numDisplays = 0;

CGGetOnlineDisplayList(10, displays, &numDisplays);

for(uint32_t i = 0; i < numDisplays; i++)
{
    [[LogManager sharedManager] logWithFormat:@">>> Found an online display!"];
}

if(numDisplays == 0)
    [[LogManager sharedManager] logWithFormat:@"<<<<< No displays!"];
```

Following the documentation in the sample on how to view the logs, the following is printed on the login screen:

`Jul 12 10:03:09 veeboxs-MacBook-Pro PreLoginAgentCocoa[3129] <Info>: Did finish launching begin
Jul 12 10:03:09 veeboxs-MacBook-Pro PreLoginAgentCocoa[3129] <Info>: Showing window with extreme prejudice
Jul 12 10:03:09 veeboxs-MacBook-Pro PreLoginAgentCocoa[3129] <Info>: Did finish launching end
Jul 12 10:03:09 veeboxs-MacBook-Pro PreLoginAgentCocoa[3129] <Info>: >>> Found an online display!`

Comment: `CGGetOnlineDisplayList()` failed to discover displays, according to what OP says.

Comment: @hidefromkgb yes, when called from a command-line app over SSH - because the window server is not accessible like that. But it is accessible from inside a pre-login agent, as in my answer.

Comment: Will this work with an application that got forked from a pre-login agent?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you be more specific over your exact requirements for this? Do you want to fork a CLI application that will handle enumerate the screens? What is the end result you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I have an application that is split into three parts. The important parts are the service, that handles connections and a process that will gather system informations, such as screen resolutions, etc. The backend that gathers infos will be forked from the service and handles different stuff via IPC.

Comment: Okay, it seems to do it. The only problem with that solution is that I need to launch the agent on demand, not everytime the loginscreen is shown.

Comment: It sounds like you may have to compromise on your design to get exactly what you want, but I suggest opening a new question with the specifics if you are stuck. Or hopefully someone will come along with a better solution to this one. Cheers!